# TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'name')

Tags: node.js, typeerror, undefined, apostrophe-cms

[This TypeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NEEI2.png)

I want to set properties of undefined (setting 'name')

Comment: Please include your code. The error states that you are trying to modify a variable that **DOESN'T** exist.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please read about [how to ask a proper "Where's the bug / Fix my code" question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253788/11107541) and apply what you learn to improve your question post? You can also read [ask] for further guidance. Can you please provide a [mre]? Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help#code](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.